# Definir valor dentro de um objeto igual ao valor anterior

Tags: javascript, node.js

Existe alguma manira de definir o valor de um objeto para ser igual ao objeto anterior?

Exemplo:

```
var obj = {a: 1, b: obj.a};
```

eu tentei usado `b: this.a` tambem mas criou uma tag circle de html, eu não entendi o porque.

Atualmente, estou conseguindo fazer isso desta maneira:

```
var obj = {a: 1, b: null};
obj.b = obj.a;
```

Existe alguma outra maneira mais eficaz?

Comment: Antes de apresentar uma resposta pergunto, o uso de uma propriedade resolveria seu problema? Exemplo: `var obj = {a: 1, get b(){return this.a}};`

Comment: não, oque eu quero é que dois ou mais elementos dentro do objeto tenham os mesmo valores.
EX: 
`var obj = {a: 1, b: /*valor ou ponteiro de a*/, c: 2, d: /*valor ou ponteiro de c*/, e: etc...}`

Comment: Antes de dizer que não é o que procura já experimentou fazer `var obj = {a: 1, get b(){return this.a}}; console.log(obj); obj.a=33; console.log(obj); console.log(obj.b);`

Comment: Eu usei o console.log(obj) e o obj.b não apareceu, mas agora vi que ele existe sim.
Desculpa ai, era isso que eu procurava mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

Você poderia utilizar o operador spread (`...`):

Um exemplo:

```
const obj = {a: 1, b: 2};
const obj1 = {c:3, ...obj};
```

ou tentar caso estiver utilizando uma versão de javascript mais antiga `Object.assign()`:

```
const obj = {a: 1, b: 1};
const obj2 = Object.assign({c:3, d: obj})
```

Para uma utilização mais completa e verificar mais exemplos recomendo visualizar a [documentação do mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

Comment: oque eu quero é definir o valor obj.b para ser igual a obj.a se possível em apenas uma linha de código